# How to load libraries (Lisp files), wherever they are located

Tags: load-path, require

I've been learning how to use modules using the `cider-mode` source code but I've run into a very basic issue.

The contents of my files are

- `main.el`

> ```
>  (require 'main-module)
>
>    (main-module-message)
>
>    (provide 'main)
> ```

- `main-module.el`

> ```
> (defun main-module-message ()
>   (message-box "this is defined in the module")
>
> (provide 'module)
> ```

When I do `(load "~/Projects/modules-test/main.el")`

It can't sense the`main-module.el` file kept inside the same directory.

Could you please point to the relevant documentation, I can't seem to find anything useful on `require` and `provide` apart from a couple paragraphs.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Projects/modules-test")
```

See docs:

- [Lisp Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html)
- [Library Search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Search.html)

The best thing you can do is <kbd>C-h v load-path RET</kbd> and follow links in the `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm)